# Redux and Redux thunk not synchronous

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

My assumption from working with redux is that dispatching actions is a synchronous task.

```
fire action 1 - > store updated
fire action 2 -> store updated
```

In a project I'm currently working on, I have a product customizer, that allows some user selection, they can place multiple orders, but if they're only ordering their current selection and select "purchase", I fire "addOrder", adding their selection to the orders array, and then the "purchase" action, which is a thunk submitting the orders stored in redux to my cart API.

I've expected that I would be able to rely on the store being in a consistent state, reliably after each action, and so when that second action fires it would have the state, as it is, after the first regular action fired before it, but no dice.

- Are my expectations and understanding of redux here incorrect?
- If so, Is redux thunk acting outside the normal dispatch in some way?

in my connected component I dispatch each action:

```
//.... inside component
purchase = () => {
  this.props.addOrder(); // regular action
  this.props.purchase(); // thunk
};
// ... rest of component
```

Comment: Can you provide a repo or codesandbox.io example of this not working? It definitely sounds like an extra middleware in the stack is injecting some asynchronicity into your store.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, did you figure out why is this happening?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, dispatching is *always* 100% synchronous, unless altered by a middleware.  And yes, by default, you can call `getState()` again after a dispatch to get the updated state:

```js
function checkStateAfterDispatch() {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        const firstState = getState();
        dispatch({type : "FIRST_ACTION"});

        const secondState = getState();

        if(secondState.someField != firstState.someField) {
            dispatch({type : "SECOND_ACTION"});
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Except when a dispatch a regular action, followed by a thunk, in my component, the getState in the thunk, almost always (race condition)  retrieves the state prior to the first action completing.  What you've explained was what I understood and expected, abut is not what I'm observing.

Comment: There is no race condition in the Redux core, period.  If you're getting the "prior" state, it's because some middleware you've added to your application is delaying the dispatched action from reaching the reducers and making it asynchronous.

Comment: the only thing I've got there is `    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk))`

Comment: You just need to read getState(), in thunk file .. This will be has correct state